# Сan't open dynamic library file (.dylib) without exporting a DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable using 'dlopen' function on Mac OS

Tags: macos, dynamic, loading

I want to dynamically load libnss3.dylib file from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/ directory on Mac OS and use some functions from it. But I have an error - "invalid handle passed to dlsym()". When I set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to directory, where this library is located - everything works fine. But sometimes I need to execute this program in sudo mode and sudo remove all variables that start with DYLD_*, so I need to find some other option to successfully execute my program.

Without environment variable I have such output in terminal when running binary:
'invalid handle passed to dlsym()'

With DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable the output is:
'Install certificate to certstore: OK'

`otool -L` option for libnss3.dylib:

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libnss3.dylib:
    @executable_path/libnss3.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 22.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 492.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ExceptionHandling.framework/Versions/A/ExceptionHandling (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 11.0.0)

`@executable_path/libmozglue.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 728.9.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)

So It has dependence from libmozglue.dylib file, but libnss3.dylib "should know where is it", or not?
Here is some code, this is the very beginning of file:

```
var (
    nsspath = C.CString("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libnss3.dylib")
libNSS = C.dlopen(nsspath, C.RTLD_LAZY)
)
if libNSS == nil {
    err := dlerror("dlopen")
    fmt.Println(err)
}
...
func dlerror(ctx string) error {
    errptr := C.dlerror()
    if errptr != nil {
        return errors.New(C.GoString(errptr))
    }
    return nil
}
```

The output of terminal is the output of fmt.Println function after `err := dlerror("dlopen")` line
Thank you for any help!

Comment: How about `install_name_tool`?

Comment: I have tried ```install_name_tool -add_rpath```,  but it doesn't work and I don't understand why. And I can not use ```install_name_tool - change``` because this file is in /Application/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/ directory and it belongs to Firefox app, so this could cause some problem. Thanks, Richard

Comment: As a start, check for errors after `dlopen`.

Comment: I added some code and explanation, thank you very much, Lorinczy